# strange output issue in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
1)  #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
  {
       int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
       int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
        printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));
        return 0;
   }
```

**the output is 2 5**. `&a` means the address of `a[0]` so  `&a+1` should be the address of `a[1]`.  So `ptr` should hold the address of `a[1]`.  `*(a+1)` will be 2 but `*(ptr-1)` should also be 2.  I can't understand how is it printing 5.

Comment: `&a` means the address of `a`, not `a[0]`. The type of `a` is `int[5]`, so `&a + 1` adds `sizeof(a)` (which is `sizeof(int) * 5`) to that address. You want to use `int *ptr = (int*)(&a[0] + 1);`

Comment: Initialize your `ptr` with `a+1` or `&a[0] + 1`, no need to cast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different Pointer Arithmetic Results when Taking Address of Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775701/different-pointer-arithmetic-results-when-taking-address-of-array)

Comment: If `ptr` did hold the address of `a[1]`, then `*(ptr - 1)` would be `1`, not `2`

Answer (score 4):

This expression is the important thing: `&a+1`. That is actually `(&a)+1` which is equal to `(&a)[1]` which will be a pointer to one element past the end of the array.

If we look at it more "graphically" it looks like this, with relevant pointers added:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | a[3] | a[4] |
+------+------+------+------+------+
^      ^                           ^
|      |                           |
|      &a[1] (equal to *(a + 1))   |
|                                  |
&a[0] (equal to a)                 |
|                                  |
&a                                 &a+1
```

First of all, the type of `&a` is `int (*)[5]`, so your cast to `int *` will break strict aliasing (which leads to *undefined behavior*).

Second of all, since `ptr` is pointing, effectively, to what would be `a[5]` then `ptr - 1` will point to `a[4]`.

Comment: Does the cast `(int*)(&a+1)` break strict aliasing or is it the subsequent de-referencing the pointer `*(ptr-1)` that may break strict aliasing?

Comment: @chux Without even attempting to dig into the specification, I would say it's the cast, since it tells the compiler that the pointer `&a+1` is something it really isn't. But don't quote me on that! :)

Comment: Thanks - Hmmm, on review I am confident `&a+1`, `(int*)(&a+1)`, and `int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);` are all well defined per `C11 §6.3.2.3 7`.  Yet this minor issue should not take more away from a good answer

Comment: @chux Since you've checked the spec., I'll trust you on that.

Comment: @chux Is [this program](https://ideone.com/zA5pMh) well defined by the standard or It is `UB` ?

Comment: @Michi Best to post such questions  as _questions_ instead of comments.

Comment: Casts never violate the strict aliasing rule. The rule is about accessing an object of type T through lvalue of type U where there does not exist certain relationship between T and U.

Answer (score 2):

`&a` gives the address of the array as an *array pointer*, `int (*)[5]`. It is a pointer type that points at the array as whole, so if you do pointer arithmetic with it, `+1` will mean `+sizeof(int[5])` which is not what you intended.

Correct code:

```
int *ptr = a+1;
```

Notably, the cast `(int*)` was hiding this bug. Don't use casts to silence compiler errors you don't understand!

Comment: `the cast (int*) was hiding this bug` What exactly happens If I change `int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);`  to  `int *ptr = *(&a+1);`. Because It seems to be the same . Now `ptr` points to `int (*)[5]` and there is no Cast.

Comment: There is no bug; the code was attempting (and succeeding) to display the last element of `a`. Your "correct code" would display the first element.

Comment: @Michi You can't convert implicitly from `int (*)[5]` to `int*`, they aren't compatible pointer types. `int *ptr = *(&a+1);` is fine except it points in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @M.M It is not really clear what the intention is. It is however clear that `&a+1` points beyond the end of the array, not at the last element. `int*` is not compatible with `int (*)[5]` nor do they necessarily alias. I don't think it is well-defined behavior to do pointer arithmetic on an array pointer and then convert to a `int*`. We can point 1 item beyond an array without invoking UB, but in this case, it ends up as 1 array beyond, not 1 int beyond.

Answer (score 2):

`&a` is **not** the address of `a[0]` but the address of `a`.  The values may be the same but the *types* are different.  That is important when it comes to pointer arithmetic.

In the expression `&a + 1`, you first have `&a` which has type `int (*)[5]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of size 5.  When you add 1 to that it actually adds `sizeof(a)` bytes to the pointer value.  So `&a + 1` actually points to one byte past the end of the array.  You then cast this expression from `int (*)[5]` to `int *` and assign it to `ptr`.

When you then evaluate `*(ptr - 1)`, the `-` operator subtracts 1 * `sizeof(int)` from the byte value of `ptr` so it now points to the last element of the array, i.e. 5, and that is what is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you said: *`&a` means the address of `a[0]` so `&a+1` should be the address of a[1] ?* No you are wrong. `&a` means address of `a` not `a[0]`. And `&a+1` means it increments by *whole array size* not just one elements size and `a+1` means address of `a[1]`.

Here

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

lets assume base address of `a` is `0x100`

```
    --------------------------------------
    |   1   |   2   |   3  |   4   |   5  |
    --------------------------------------
   0x100   0x104   0x108   0x112  0x116 ..  
   LSB
    |
    a
```

When you are doing

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
```

Where `ptr` points ? first `(&a+1)` performed and it got *increments by whole array size* i.e

```
(&a+1) == (0x100 + 1*20) /* &a+1 here it increments by array size */
       == 0x120
```

So now `ptr` points to

```
    --------------------------------------
    |   1   |   2   |   3  |   4   |   5  |
    --------------------------------------
   0x100   0x104   0x108   0x112  0x116  0x120  
    a                                     |
                                         ptr points here
```

Now when you print like

```
printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));
```

Here

```
*(a+1) == *(0x100 + 1*4) /* multiplied by 4 bcz of elements is of int type*/
       == *(0x104) /* value at 0x104 location */
       == 2 (it prints 2)
```

And

```
*(ptr-1)  == *(0x120 - 1*4)
          == *(0x116) /* prints value at 0x116 memory location */
          == 5
```

**Note :-** Here

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
```

type of `&a` is of `int(*)[5]` i.e pointer to an array of 5 elements but you are casting as of `int*` type, as pointed by @someprogrammerdude it breaks the strict aliasing and lead to undefined behavior.

Correct one is

```
int *ptr = a+1;
```