# Linked List in C - Problems with a void

Tags: c

I can't understand why this part of code doesn't build and run... I have checked it again and again but I can;t find the problem.The problem is at Insert void 2nd line.

```
struct Node { 
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head;

void Insert(int x){
    struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    (*temp).data = x;
    (*temp).next = NULL;
}

void Print(){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("List is :\n");
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    head = NULL;
    printf("How many numbers ?\n";)
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
        printf("Enter the number \n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        Insert(x);
        Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your seem to imply that it doesn't compile. What error message do you get?

Comment: Get rid of the cast.  Not only is it unnecessary, but also wrong (assuming `Node` isn't a typedef).

Comment: replace `(Node*)` with `(struct Node*)` or just lose the cast entirely.

Comment: So many thanks Morten Jensen! I am new to programming so I apologize for the newbie question!

Comment: no problem @Nmpal - also check this statement `printf("How many numbers ?\n";)` <-- the semi-colon should be outside the parenthesis like this `();`

Comment: Thank you again! It works great !

Comment: You also never update `head`, so you're never adding anything to your list

Comment: Add this to your print function: `if ( temp == NULL ){
        printf("Error, NULL Pointer detected ->> Print()\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }` and you will notice the problem.

Comment: @Nmpal Try to understand [This DEMO](https://ideone.com/gtIVjN) .

Answer (score 2):

1. The -> operator is better to use with struct pointers.
2. Do you want to use this node after calling the method? If yes, try to return the pointer.
3. As @dbush pointed, you did not use the typedef keyword. Therefore, you need to change the 'Node*' in your casting to 'struct Node*'.

Comment: `The -> operator is better to use with struct pointers.` There is no reason to say that. The `->` Operator is there for a better "understanding" and not for being better than `(*).`

Comment: @Michi: There is every reason not to use `(*(*(*(*ptr1).ptr2).ptr3).ptr4).member` instead of `ptr1->ptr2->ptr3->ptr4->member` (assuming there's a justification for having such nested structures in the first place).  Notationally, the arrow notation `ptr->member` is dramatically superior to the `(*ptr).member` notation; doubly so when there's more than one level.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am agree. But We can not say that is **"better"** to use `->` instead of `(*).`

Comment: @Michi — yes, we can say that it is better to use arrow than parentheses-star-dot to a beginner.  If they learn to program according to orthodox rules, life will be easier for everyone (us, them, their tutor, their colleagues).  It is helpful to point out stylistic issues — I routinely point out that neither dot `.` nor arrow `->` should have spaces around them; they bind extremely tightly and should be written to match.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agree again. I remember tree years ago when I started to learn `C` and people here told me to not use something like this `*( *( a + i ) + j )` and I should use `a[i][j]`. I needed more than 6 months to understand Pointers just because I decided to not use `*( *( a + i ) + j )`. So from my (still) beginner side, I'm going to stick with Pointer notation.

Comment: @Michi: Your choice.  I find `*(*(a+i)+j)` (with or without the extra spacing) ridiculously hard to read compared with `a[i][j]` (which needs no extra spacing).  I'd strongly counsel against using the star-parentheses notation for array subscripting too — I nearly brought it up in one of my previous ripostes, but decided against.  Evidently, I should have.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for that. Could you please leave me an explanation [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043235/strange-output-issue-in-c/51043333#51043333)? On Lundin's Answer.

Comment: @Michi: I need to go to the office and pretend to get some work done.  I aim to follow up later.  Using `&a` where `a` is an array (which is what the other question seems to be about) is subtle (as in, not normally explained in beginning C courses because it fries the mind struggling to learn pointers at all).  Given `int a[5];`, `&a` is of type `int (*)[5]`, which is quite different from `int *` as you can see from the spelling.  If it's any consolation, pointers to functions are even more abstruse — and the abuses of `*` and `&` associated with them are weirder still.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to achieve something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tag_Node Node;

struct tag_Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void Insert(Node *to, int x) {
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->data = x;
    node->next = 0;
    to->next = node;
}
```

Assuming that you want to implement a linked list, you should have an additional parameter in your `Insert` method, which will specify the node you should insert your next value to. You will also need to use struct dereference operator (`->`) if you work with pointers.

Comment: this code doesn't even compile - the typedef is missing a name and you can't reference `Node*` inside the struct before you've typedef'd it.....

Comment: What compiler do you use? Compiled and works fine with MSVC.

Comment: MSVC is a C++ compiler. This question is regarding C. This code will not compile with any standards compliant C compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer after you first comment. You can disable C++ extensions in MSVC, so it will act like a C compiler.

Comment: Note that the standalone `struct tag_Node;` line isn't necessary; the subsequent `typedef struct tag_Node Node;` does the same job (again).  The standalone line would be necessary if there was a function prototype like `int count_Nodes(struct tag_Node *list);` before the `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
struct Node* node = (Node*)...;
```

C's type system is a bit less forgiving than it used to be: it won't promote this thing `Node*` into a `struct Node*`.

You need

```
struct Node* node = (struct Node*)...;
```

or you could rely on `void*`'s promotion rules, which on modern compilers will promote to any pointer type.

```
struct Node* node = ...; /* assuming ... returns a void* */
```

Comment: A bit less forgiving.. than what? (Presumably C++ but you didn't say :P)

Comment: Older C compilers would emit warnings because they didn't honor the new standard permitting void* promotion to (whatever).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two things wrong with your code.

You're using `(Node*)` in the cast where it should have been `(struct Node*)` or you can even omit it.

```
void Insert(int x){
    struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    (*temp).data = x;
    (*temp).next = NULL;
}
```

You have an error with your semi-colon in this statement as well:

```
printf("How many numbers ?\n";)
```

Replace with

```
printf("How many numbers ?\n");
```