# &array[0], &array or array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand the logic between the three writing: `array`, `&array` and `&array[0]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *a);
void bar(int (*a)[3]);
void baz(int a[3]);

int main(void) {
    int array[] = {1,2,3};

    int* a = array;
    int (*b)[sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])] = &array;
    int* c = &array[0];

    printf("%p, %p, %p", a, b, c);
}
```

I always thought `int a[]` is a kind-of `int *`. And in fact it works:

```
int *p = array;
```

But the address of a pointer to an `int` is `int**`:

```
int *u;
int **v = &u;
```

However here, the adresse of `array` is not `int**` but `int (*)[3]`. I am lost.

What does the standard says about `&array`?

Comment: Lose the notion "`int a[]` is a kind-of `int *`" and then there is no confusion. The array of ints is several single `int`s next to each other in memory. It has an address just like any other variable

Comment: I would accept that, but what is precisely `int a[]` then ?

Comment: dupe of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807208/why-are-array-and-array-pointing-to-the-same-address

Comment: more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775701/different-pointer-arithmetic-results-when-taking-address-of-array

Comment: @nowox an array, which I explained in my first comment