# C++ Pointers: `*(&array`) is same as `array` and `&array`

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++ name of the array without a bracket, is a pointer to the first element of the array. However, I couldn't realize how the following code works

```
int main()
{
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;    
    cout << "&x = " << &x << endl;
    cout << "*(&x) = " << *(&x) << endl;
    cout << "*x = " << *x << endl;
    cout << "**(&x) = " << **(&x) << endl;
}
```

and this is the output

```
x = 0x7ffd179e9060
&x = 0x7ffd179e9060
*(&x) = 0x7ffd179e9060
*x = 1
**(&x) = 1
```

What I don't understand is

1. why does `x = &x = 0x7ffd179e9060`?
2. if `x = &x = 0x7ffd179e9060`, then must be `*x = *(&x)` while `*x=1` and `*(&x) = 0x7ffd179e9060`
3. Why pointer to pointer `**(&x) = 1` is working here?

Thanks in advance.

Question [Why are `&array` and `array` pointing to the same address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807208/why-are-array-and-array-pointing-to-the-same-address)is not an answer to my question.

Comment: "_In C++ name of the array without a bracket, is a pointer to the first element of the array._": This is wrong and probably causes your confusion. There should be a hundred duplicates on this here.

Comment: `x` and `&x` are not the same, they are both pointers, pointing at the same address (which is why they print the same value) but the first is a pointer to the first element, and the second is a pointer to the array. In other words they are both pointers but the type is different,

Comment: This also explains why `*x` and `*(&x)` are different, and why `**(&x)` works.

Comment: Near duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8916656/179910

Comment: Side note this way of working with arrays (and naked pointers) is more for "C" *And yes I know this is still being taught as part of datastructure classes). But in C++ use std::array or std::vector to avoid pointer decay of arrays (the situation where you only have the pointer to the first element of an array, but all size information is lost)

Comment: @JerryCoffin please read both questions and then vote for duplicate OK? The question you mentioned is not even near my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&x`, `&(x)` and `(&x)` are all the same.

As an expression, plain `x` is the same as `&x[0]`. Which is very different from `&x`.

`&x` is a pointer to the array itself, and will have the type `int (*)[4]`. `&x[0]` is a pointer to the first element of the array and will have the type `int*`.

The reason both `&x` and `&x[0]` points to the same location is easy to understand if we *draw* it:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| x[0] | x[1] | x[2] | x[3] |
+------+------+------+------+
^
|
&x
|
&x[0]
```

As you noticed, and which can easily be seen in the drawing above, both `&x` and `&x[0]` are pointing to the same location. But they have different types.

Also, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`. From this it's possible to deduce that `*p` is the same as `p[0]`. So `*(&x)` is the same as `(&x)[0]` which is the same as `x`.

Answer (score 6):

> In C++ name of the array without a bracket, is a pointer to the first element of the array

It may *seem* like this, but this isn't really what is happening.  The name of an array is the name of the array and denotes the array.  What *actually* happens is that whenever you use an array-typed expression in an rvalue context, it get implicitly converted into a pointer to the array's first element.

Since *most* contexts are rvalue contexts, it may seem like the array is always the same as a pointer to the first element, but the details sometimes matter.  In particular, the operand of a unary `&` is not an rvalue context, so when you say `&x` you get a pointer to the array as a whole.  Thus `x` and `&x` end up appearing to have the same value, and the actual bit pattern of the pointer is the same; all that is different is the type.

Comment: In `sizeof(array)`, there's no conversion either, so you get the size of the array, not the size of a pointer.

Comment: sizeof, like &, is not an rvalue context.  Neither are a number of other things.

Comment: Why pointer to pointer **(&x) = 1 is working here?

Comment: The `&` gives you a pointer to the array, which the first `*` removes (giving you back the array).  That is then implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element (operand of `*` is an rvalue context), and that second `*` give you the array's first element.  The `=` then assigns to value 1 to that first array element.